# How to create a user account profile with django (front end)

Tags: html, django

I have an ongoing project that i am building with the DJANGO webframework. I have successfully created a registration page and upon successful registration and login;

## Where i need your help

1. When a user logs-in into his account, I want that user to be able to see his account, profile and recent actions.(NB: from the front end and not the Django admin end)
2. Is it advisable to have 2 different apps, and i want to associate the user input submitted on one app to a registered user on the other app?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Django userena](http://www.django-userena.org/) can be used to save and display user profile and it can be customized for our needs(to display account information and recent actions).
2. Django multi-database routing concept can be used to share users and sessions across projects. It is explained more clearly [here](http://dustinfarris.com/2012/2/sharing-django-users-and-sessions-across-projects/).